# Архитектуры HighLoad

Tags: highload

Кто знает - опишите пожалуйста архитектуру какого нибудь высоко нагруженного динамического web сайта с возможностью горизонтального масштабирования.За раннее спасибо за ответы!

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите в эту сторону, базовая версия бесплатная: [XenServer](http://www.citrix.com/English/ps2/products/product.asp?contentID=683148&ntref=prod_top). [Ставим и настраиваем XEN сервер](http://sudouser.com/stavim-i-nastraivaem-xen-server.html).